# Wordpress + All-in-one Event calendar

Tags: wordpress

i have wordpress installed, and am using all-in-one event calendar. What i need is when viewing event, i want the template to be full with. But now it shows some other template, like there is a sidebar, even if i show it only on homepage. Here is an example - http://veebimeedia.ee/seeder/ai1ec_event/event/?instance_id=13

I need events displayed in full width template. I have read that this plugin uses default posts template, but where i can change that? I have no single.php in my theme.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS around line 545 your have set:

```
#content { float: left; width: 595px; margin: 0; min-height: 180px; }
```

All elements width under #content will not be more then 595px width.

I would the template of the page to no sidebar. Or make a new template where you delete the sidebar, and make it say something else then #content. (example #content-full) and then set the CSS.

```
#content-full { float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0; min-height: 180px; }
```

But still it is hard to tell how the theme is built up.

Comment: Thanks, i changed singular.php in my theme, instead of #content div i now use div with has width: 100%

Comment: Notice that if "singular"(single.php) is used in more then one place. It will change the width on all places. That's why it is good to have a template to change too if you dont want it on a specific page.

Comment: +1 Creating a separate template for this is the correct way to go.

Comment: @user1612619 you should upvotes any correct answers (this one included) as well as accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you set the full width template on the page not the post.  Most themes have a template with no sidebars.  If not you can make one by duplicating the page.php file, give it a new name and a template name and remove the sidebar call.

Comment: It's says - No templates exist for this post type.

Comment: it's a page attribute, not a post attribute that controls the template.

Comment: I copied full width template content to page.php, it doesn't change anything.